# Can anyone clarify the error in my switch statement?

Tags: c, for-loop, switch-statement, cs50, c-strings

I keep getting this error for my switch statement when I compile it:

> "scrabble.c:50:9: error: statement requires expression of integer type
> ('string' (aka 'char
> *') invalid)
> switch (word)
> ^       ~~~~
> fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]"

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// complete the compute_score function
// return the number of points for the word
// ignore non-letter words
// handle both upper-case and lower-case letters
// in main, Print: "player 1 wins!" or "player 2 wins!" or "Tie!".

// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 
10};

int compute_score(string word);

int main(void)
{
    // Get input words from both players
    string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");

    // Score both words
    int score1 = compute_score(word1);
    int score2 = compute_score(word2);

    // TODO: Print the winner
    if (score1 > score2)
    {
        printf("Player 1 Wins!\n");
    }
    else if (score1 < score2)
    {
        printf("Player2 Wins!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("It's a TIE!");
    }
}

int compute_score(string word)
{
    // TODO: Compute and return score for string
    int score = 0;
    int length = strlen(word);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
   {
        switch (word)
        {
        case isupper(word[i]):
            score += Points(word[i] - '65');
            Break;
        case islower(word[i]):
            score += Points(word[i] - '97');
            Break;
        }
        return score;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `switch` only with integer types, not strings.

Comment: @wohlstad: The source code includes the well-known `cs50.h` header, which defines `string` to be `char *`.

Comment: The function calls can only be evaluated at runtime; the values in a `case` label must be valuable at compile time.  You will need to use `if` and `else if`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks. I was not familiar with `cs50.h`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message means what it says: A `switch` statement requires an expression of integer type.

`word` is not an integer type. It is a `string`, which is defined to be `char *`. You cannot use a `switch` statement to select among abstract notions or computed expressions in the cases. You can only use a `switch` statement if you can give a specific integer value to be used for the selection.

Rewrite your program to use `if` statements instead of a `switch`.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the feedback. I've fixed the problem. Just as a side question: is there anyway to get around this without using an if statement in c like other languages?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `word` has the type `string` that is a typedef name for the pointer type `char *`. But the expression in the switch statement shall have an integer type. So this switch statement

```
switch (word)
```

is incorrect.

Also case labels shall have integer constant expressions. Thus these case labels

```
case isupper(word[i]):
```

and

```
case islower(word[i]):
```

are incorrect because the function calls `isupper` and `islower` return run-time values that are not integer constant expressions.

From the C Standard (6.8.4.2 The switch statement)

> 3 **The expression of each case label shall be an integer constant
> expression** and no two of the case constant expressions in the same
> switch statement shall have the same value after conversion. There may
> be at most one default label in a switch statement. (Any enclosed
> switch statement may have a default label or case constant expressions
> with values that duplicate case constant expressions in the enclosing
> switch statement.)

Use if-else statement instead of the switch

```
    if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )word[i]) )
    {
        score += Points(word[i] - 'A');
    }
    else if islower( ( unsigned char )word[i] )
    {
        score += Points(word[i] - 'a');
    }
```

Also place the return statement outside the for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    //...
}
return score;
```

Pay attention to that the call of the function `strlen` is redundant. You could write the for loop like

```
for ( ; *word != '\0'; ++word )
{
    if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )*word ) )
    {
        score += Points( *word - 'A');
    }
    else if islower( ( unsigned char )*word )
    {
        score += Points( *word - 'a');
    }
}

return score;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the feedback I have remedied the problem as such:

```c
int score = 0;
int length = strlen(word);

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if (isupper(word[i]))
    {
        score = score + POINTS[word[i] - 65];
    }
    else if (islower(word[i]))
    {
        score = score + POINTS[word[i] - 97];
    }
}
return score;
```